# What causes a high budget title to be direct-to-DVD?

Tags: distribution

We've all heard the saying "released straight to DVD" to indicate the failure of a movie to make it into the theaters. Now, I'm not talking about the "made for DVD" films, or foreign films that were released there in theaters and then find there way here only on DVD. I'm also excluding indie films that were produced but couldn't find a theater distributor.

I'm talking about when the phrase is used to refer to the failure of a major film. "It sucked so bad it went straight to DVD". Is this saying true, or is it just a saying / myth.

Has there been a major film by a professional studio that when it was finished. It went straight to DVD and skipped the theaters?

p.s. DVD and BluRay, yea the same thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes - this happens all the time, and there are hundreds of larger-budget films that go directly to DVD either because test screenings fell flat or the distributors got cold feet.

Big names including Pacino, Statham and Butler are not immune to this, and to prevent this question and answer turning into a long list, [here is a link to Hollywood.com](http://www.hollywood.com/static/the-top-10-highest-profile-straight-to-dvd-releases) which profiles ten of the most recent direct-to-DVD releases.